# Разложение натурального числа > 1

Tags: python

Нужно сделать функцию, которая берет любое натуральное число > 1 и раскладывает его на сумму из чисел 1 и 2. То есть, если допустим берем число n=3, то через пробел должны вывести в таком виде...

1 1 1

1 2

2 1

Comment: Уточняющий вопрос - нужно кому?

Comment: @Vlad ребята на данном сайте по своей сути альтруисты. Люди стараются помочь друг другу и тем, у кого возникают сложности. Постарайтесь оформлять Ваш вопрос в виде вопроса, а не хаотичной задачи, а так же обязательно выкладывайте то, что пытались сделать самостоятельно. Это не тот портал, где за Вас бесплатно будут выполнять Ваши задачи. Главная цель - помочь, подсказать.

Comment: Сессия никак не отпустит... Радует то, что к концу сессии и на перездачах преподы уже поняли что сложных вопросов можно не задавать. И задают что-то из 6-7-го класса средней школы.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот пример такой функции

```
def decomposition(n, vector):
    if n==0:
        print(vector)
    else:
        if n-1>=0:
            decomposition(n-1,vector+[1])
        if n-2>=0:
            decomposition(n - 2, vector + [2])

res=[]
decomposition(5,res)
```

результат работы

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 2]
[1, 1, 2, 1]
[1, 2, 1, 1]
[1, 2, 2]
[2, 1, 1, 1]
[2, 1, 2]
[2, 2, 1]
```